# What is the name of that book which talks of a friend of Krishna called Chhandak?

Tags: identification-request, hindi-language

I read in a book having seven parts/volumes that there was a friend of Krishna called Chhandak who was always with Krishna.

It also talked about someone who could not speak but wanted to learn flute from Krishna, and for Dakshina, was about to give his thumb. It was when Krishna was with his Guru. It talks about the time and the feeling of Krishna when whole Yadav once was destroyed and he met with Rishi Durvasa; Rishi Durvasa heard that the whole Kaurav Line was destroyed and Krishna did nothing then Rishi durvasa was about to curse Krishna but Krishna's aura of God appeared and Rishi Durvasa calmed down.

Can someone provide me the name of the book?

Although I don't myself think that someone called Chhandak really existed, specially who was always with Krishna but the way it is written in that book. I liked that so I want to read the other parts of it.

Where I read Library : DAVV, Indore, India.

Comment: Sorry for the edit clash; I edited in the info from your comment not knowing that you were about to do the same. Your info about *where* you read it (a library in India?) might be worth adding back in though. Our [story-ID tag info page](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info) has more advice on how to write a good ID question.

Comment: Are you confusing the guy with Eklavya, maybe?

Comment: छंदक Was the name of the character..I think I have to to go there and ask for someone's help since i'm no longer student there so I can't go inside.

Comment: @PranitaGupta - Here - https://books.google.co.in/books?id=B49ZDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT75&lpg=PT75&dq=%E0%A4%9B%E0%A4%82%E0%A4%A6%E0%A4%95&source=bl&ots=5-0u--hjdp&sig=ACfU3U3eCrowG3JtZbfQIJ777-sTmB672A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiW2sKNjbjkAhWLQY8KHQ0SDMsQ6AEwJ3oECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=%E0%A4%9B%E0%A4%82%E0%A4%A6%E0%A4%95&f=false The book is in Hindi and also there is mentioning of Chandak in that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The series you are thinking of is probably [कृष्ण की आत्मकथा](https://www.goodreads.com/series/184108-krishna-ki-atmakatha) (*kR^iShNa kii aatmakathaa*, *The Autobiography of Krishna*) by Manu Sharma. The series has eight volumes, but it does include a character Chhandak. You are of course correct that there is no close friend of Krishna's named Chhandak mentioned in earlier mythology, but since Sharma's series is fiction, he has invented this character. Chhandak is particularly present in the fourth volume, लाक्षागृह (*laakShaagR^iha*, *The House of Lac*). A reviewer named Sachin Kaushik writes on [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/17661251):

> Though Chchandak is one character i havent been able to find if he really existed, he plays a central part in almost all the events.

So this sounds like the series you are looking for.